# Can't Update product attribute from magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.7, php, multistore, store-view

After editing short description from magento admin panel and clicking on save, it shows message that it was saved successfully, but the short description was same before editing. I hope this issue is because of store view.

But to change short description if the store view is changed from default to some other then it gets updated, but i cant change its value for all store views

Has anyone else experienced this, and, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you refresh Magento Cache?

Comment: Yes. Still its like that.
Tried reindexing too.That doesn't work

Comment: Before saving in controller form data has correct updated values, but after save, printing product model shows the old values of the product before saving. Can any one help in this ?

Comment: @user4253 what is this for, product/category or some custom module? Is the database entry updated or nothing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with mysql server, after a transaction it rollbacks the transcation. So I reinstalled Mysql, that solved the issue.. **Thanks for all**

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

you need to identify the attribute ids for all global attributes then delete all the values from the `catalog_product_entity_*` tables that have the attribute id one of those identified above and the store id field not zero.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` 
WHERE
   store_id <> 0 AND
   attribute_id IN (
           SELECT attribute_id 
           FROM catalog_eav_attribute 
           WHERE is_global = 1

   )
```

Do the same for the tables `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, `catalog_product_entity_text`, `catalog_product_entity_datetime`, `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.

Rebuild your indexes when your are done.

Note: The select from `catalog_eav_attribute` in the way I wrote it will give you attribute ids for the global category attributes also, but that's not important since in the product tables you don't have category attributes references.

Also, before trying this, backup your database in case I missed something.

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42763/6501
Thanks to: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius

Answer (score 0):

Try re-indexing data and flushing cache from Magento Admin.

System -> Index Management

System -> Cache Management