# Global product attribute empty on store view level

Tags: attributes, configuration, product-attribute

We have a strange situation. A global product attribute that is populated at the default config level is empty on store view level. The attribute scope is ofcourse set to global. See the image below to demonstrate.

Now I must admit that we needed to tweak the database eav_attribute: because we had defined these attributes as text when they should be dropdown.

The problem arises on the frontend where these attributes default to NO,NO NO as their values. And another interesting fact is that this only happens to configurable products that have been with us for some years. The lower SKU's ....

**Store set-up**

```
-- Main config 
|---- Store view 1 (current) 
|---- Store view 2 (new)
```

For example: Main config has a (global) setting with value A. Store view 2 shows this value A. But Store view 1 shows value "empty".

**Question:** anyone encountered this before?

Can it be that a value already existed on a store view level? [but manually changing and saving it on the store view level does nothing. They stay empty]

**On default config level**
[image]

**On store view level**
[image]

Comment: I recently had a similar situation with some categories that I had created programatically. The simple solution for me was to clone the categories. You can clone the products in admin to 'fix' this with them saving the proper Magento way and 'fixing' themselves. Can be easier than a programming solution.

Comment: Hmmm. You mean duplicate? Can give it a try

Comment: Strangest thing. I just realized that our second store view (new) DOES show the correct values. SO only the already existing store hass this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick fix.
you need to identify the attribute ids for all global attributes then delete all the values from the `catalog_product_entity_*` tables that have the attribute id one of those identified above and the store id field not zero.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` 
WHERE
   store_id <> 0 AND
   attribute_id IN (
           SELECT attribute_id 
           FROM catalog_eav_attribute 
           WHERE is_global = 1

   )
```

Do the same for the tables `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, `catalog_product_entity_text`, `catalog_product_entity_datetime`, `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.

Rebuild your indexes when your are done.

Note: The select from `catalog_eav_attribute` in the way I wrote it will give you attribute ids for the global category attributes also, but that's not important since in the product tables you don't have category attributes references.

Also, before trying this, backup your database in case I missed something.

Comment: This is the only real solution! Many thanks.

Comment: okay but how to do it programatically ? I mean using datapatch ? Thanks.